# Saving the state of an activity before pressing the back button

Tags: java, android

I am currently building an android app which requires saving the state of my variables and views when the back button is pressed. I know the onSaveInstanceState() would work for scenarios which involve change in orientation but how do I get it to save when I use the back button.

Answer (score 0):

You may override `finish()` method and do saving there. This method is called when the activity is finished — that means, it's removed from activity stack. By default this happens when you press back button.

Comment: Can you explain further please?

Comment: onFinish() ? Have not heard about such a function in Android? I did search in developer site but was not able to find it. Which class does it belong to?

Comment: @prijupaul Oops, I forgot the name. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You can override,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and save the state in Shared Preferences.

Comment: but if the user leaves the activity by doing something else (for example, "up navigation", or launches another activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag, state will be lost.

Comment: Right. but @Jack wants it on back button press.

Answer (score -1):

As Sarge said, you can override onFinish() and save the data in preferences, AppDelegate, etc. Or you can save the data and send it to the previous activity for an activityResult, or you can try to find the proper activity flag so this activity won't get killed.

Comment: such a function onFinish() does not exist in Android.